# Converting a lead while workflow is active

Tags: lead-conversion

I have a time-based workflow on my lead, which acts on a date field. If a lead is inactive for 30 days, then it is assigned to a queue. The problem is that a lead cannot be converted if I have this workflow active. So, I added a checkbox to the lead object, and when this checkbox is ticked, the workflow is broken.
The problem now is that I obviously don't want to click that checkbox everytime before I want to convert a lead, so I was wondering if there is an easy way of doing this behind the scenes?

Option 2 of the answer by @jpmonette sounds very good, I was just wondering whether I need to rebuild all the logic of converting a lead, or is there a possiblity to create a link to that process?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1. Use a Scheduled Apex running on a daily basis replicating the logic of that Time-based workflow.
2. Keep that checkbox & create a replica of your `Convert Lead` button, with some JavaScript to automatically populate that checkbox on click.

Comment: Thanks @jpmonette - for option 2, is it possible to link to all the convert lead logic when I create a new button, or will I have to create a New Account, New Opportunity myself?